# Is it possible to configure google docs V2 to use one account in alfresco?

Tags: google-docs, alfresco, alfresco-share

Is it possible to have all users editing a document using google docs not to have to enter a username and password by configuring alfresco to use a master username and password?
The following:

```
# Enables Goggle Editable functionality set to true to enable
googledocs.googleeditable.enabled=true

# Google Docs system authentication credentials account Alfresco will use a tempt account 
# for everyone
googledocs.username=your_account@gmail.com
googledocs.password=your_gmail_password
```

aside from the `googledocs.googleeditable.enabled=true` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible to have the Alfresco Google Docs v2 integration use a single user account.  By design the new version documents are edited per user using their google account.